# Find most frequent word in string variables

Tags: stata

I have a string variable with different colors:

```
gen cols="red green red red blue maroon green pink"
```

I want to find which color in this list appears most frequently.

I tried the `count` command but this produces wrong results.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to ask high quality reproducible questions in Stata](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377015/) for help on writing Stata-related questions that are useful to all users of this site.

Answer (score 1):

There is a community-contributed command that does this in one. `tabsplit` from `tab_chi` on SSC is designed for this purpose.

```
clear 

input strL (colors numbers) 
"red green red red blue maroon green pink" "87 45 65 87 98 12 90 43"
end

tabsplit colors, sort 

     colors |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
        red |          3       37.50       37.50
      green |          2       25.00       62.50
       blue |          1       12.50       75.00
     maroon |          1       12.50       87.50
       pink |          1       12.50      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
      Total |          8      100.00


tabsplit numbers, sort 

    numbers |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
         87 |          2       25.00       25.00
         12 |          1       12.50       37.50
         43 |          1       12.50       50.00
         45 |          1       12.50       62.50
         65 |          1       12.50       75.00
         90 |          1       12.50       87.50
         98 |          1       12.50      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
      Total |          8      100.00

.
```

EDIT As documented in its help, `tabsplit` allows options of `tabulate` as appropriate, including those for saving results. However, that is not especially helpful here as `matrow()` won't work for string variables. That isn't documented directly but follows from the principle that Stata matrices can't hold strings. `matcell()` does work here, but knowing the frequencies alone is not especially helpful. The overarching principle is that for many questions involving words within strings a structure with single words in each value of a string variable is much easier to work with.

Comment: Very nice indeed! I have to admit I had no idea about this command of yours.

Comment: Thanks! It's not very long. It lets `split`, `stack` and  `tabulate` do most of the work.

Comment: @Suji `matcell` will work in cases where you have seen the output of `tabulate`. But if you are trying to program a series of such calculations it will be impossible to know which value (color/number here) corresponds to the highest frequency.